# Augularjs keep failing me for injecting ngTable module

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs 1.5.7 and keep getting below error:

angular.min.js:117 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=ngTableProvider%20%3C-%20ngTable%20%3C-%20CustomerBuyController at Error (native)

The following are what I have done

```
**index.html**
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <link href="css/vendor/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>

...

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/controller-customer-buy.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

**app.js**
var app = angular.module('myapp',["ngRoute", "ngTable"]);

**route.js**
angular.module('myapp').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location, $rootScope){
      // Initialize a new promise
      var deferred = $q.defer();

     if(!sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) {

          $location.url('/login');
          deferred.resolve();

      } else {

          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8008/is-valid-user-token',
              data: { 
                token: sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')
              }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {

              $location.url('/buy');  

              deferred.resolve();

          }, function errorCallback(response) {

              $location.url('/login');

              deferred.reject();

          });  

      }

      return deferred.promise;

    };

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location) {
      return {
        response: function(response) {
          // do something on success
          return response;
        },
        responseError: function(response) {
          if (response.status === 401)
            $location.url('/login');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      };
    });

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/home.html'
    })

    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/login.html',
      controller  : 'LoginController',
      resolve: {
          loggedin: checkLoggedin
      }            
    })  

    .when('/buy', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/customer-buy.html',
      controller  : 'CustomerBuyController',
      resolve: {
          loggedin: checkLoggedin
      }            
    })   

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}); 

}).run(function($rootScope, $http, $location){

    // ......

});

**controller-customer-buy.js**
(function () {

      'use strict';

      angular.module('myapp').controller('CustomerBuyController', 
            ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$parse', '$http', 'ngTable' ,function($rootScope, $scope, $parse, $http, ngTable) {

      });

})();
```

Comment: u no need to call the ngTable inside your CustomerBuyCampaignController if u mention in the config (angular.module('myapp',["ngRoute", "ngTable"])  thats enough just remove and check once in controller

Comment: Do you mean           angular.module('myapp',['ngTable']).controller('CustomerBuyController', 
            ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$parse', '$http', 'ngTable' ,function($rootScope, $scope, $parse, $http, ngTable) {
    
          });

Comment: You don't inject `ngTable` into your controller. There are other ng-table modules you can inject (such as `NgTableParms`, for example).

Comment: yes dont inject in controller just remove and check

Comment: cool it is working now. thanks guys :)